# How to compare $watch Old value and new value

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I am using `$watch` for listening to `myData` which is an array. In a button click I am inserting a new element into the array. I need to find the position of the newly added element from the `newValue` array ,which is a parameter in `$watch`.

```
$scope.myData = [{
            "name": "karthik ",
            "age": 24
        },
        {
            "name": "Vijay ",
            "age": 24,
        },
        {
            "name": "Krish",
            "age": 26,
        }];


var newData = {
    "name": "viki",
    "age": 25
}
myData.splice(2, 0, newData);
```

In the **link function** I have

```
scope.$watchCollection(function(scope) {
    return scope.myData;
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal);
    console.log(oldVal);
});
```

Comment: scope.myData,indexOf(newVal)?

Comment: ok.let me make it clear! how to compare two array ?  ( oldVal and newVal)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference second answer

Comment: Post the code, where you are inserting element, what you are inserting and what is the value of myData

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use `angular.equal` to compare the two `values` , `objects`, `arrays`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals

and as according to your statement you want the new inserted element in the array. Then after inserting element in array if you are not doing any operation of array then inserted element is the last element which you can simply retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement,  ***I need to find the position of the newly added element from the newValue array.***

I created a `function` to get the **changed array value and also the index where it is added.**

**Here is the function,**

```
function difference(a1, a2) { 
  var result = { array: [], index: 0};
  for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
    if (a2.indexOf(a1[i]) === -1) {
      result.array.push(a1[i]);
      result.index = i 
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

You can call it using,  `difference(newVal,oldVal)`

```
scope.$watchCollection(function(scope) {
    return scope.myData;
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal);
    console.log(oldVal);
    var diff = difference(newVal,oldVal)
    console.log(diff)
});
```

Eg:

```
var diff = difference([1,2,3,[2,4],4],[1,2,3,4])

O/P: {array: [2,4], index: 3}
```

Comment: this will be working fine. but in the case of large data such as  a1.length = 10,000 or 1,00,000 then performance will be affected know.so is there any other way?

Comment: if you want to find the index of an added element, you need to obviously loop through the array.